# How can I convert my Python No Console code into An Android Package (APK)

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, code-conversion

Converting python to apk file.

Hello, I have got a Python programme in windows and linux, and I have just prepared it for Android System, and I want to convert my python application into a APK file. My programme has not got any user interface and my application is an background app so I do not need a GUI. I had tried to convert it on Linux with Kivy,Buildozer but I took error about to execute the last command. What should I do? My programmes requirements:

- It is a background app.- It must to take internet permission.

- It must to run with system permission because user should not stop the application and user should not remove the application from the system.                                                                                                                                       -Since the program is a system cleaning service application, it should never, ever be stopped or removed from the system once it has been run. To do this, the program can be made to run without the user knowing about it.

So, I want to convert my application to APK without lose this requirements. Thanks for help.
NOTE: If it is required I can convert my python code to other programming codes. But I can not convert it to kotlin or java with Android Studio because it is not working.